# Задать высоту виджета, такую же как ширину

Tags: android, android-widgets

Есть виджет GridView. Нужно задать высоту, такую же как ширину. Ширина заранее не известна, она задается как match_constraint, чтобы виджет растянулся по всей ширине экрана.

В целом задача в том, чтобы сделать матрицу NxN с квадратными кнопками. Если ширина и высота GridView будет одинаковая, то и кнопки будут квадратные. Пока что они выглядят как прямоугольники.

[image: Скриншот с кнопками]
[image: Xml код GridView]

Comment: Не вставляйте скриншоты кода, копируйте сам код.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решил проблему.
Вот пример кода, где создается GridView c одинаковой шириной и высотой, растянутый по ширине экрана.

activity_main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <GridView
        android:id="@+id/mGridView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:numColumns="3"
        android:horizontalSpacing="0dp"
        android:verticalSpacing="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

MainActivity.java:

```
import android.graphics.Point;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.Display;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.GridView;
import java.util.ArrayList;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements OnClickListener
{
    int AMOUNT_CELLS = 9;

    ArrayList<Button> cells;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        createButtons();
        createGridView();
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v)
    {
        ((Button) v).setText("X");
    }

    int getCellWidth()
    {
        Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
        Point size = new Point();
        display.getSize(size);
        return size.x / (int) Math.sqrt(AMOUNT_CELLS);
    }

    void createButtons()
    {
        int cellWidth = getCellWidth();
        cells = new ArrayList<>(AMOUNT_CELLS);
        Button cell;

        for (int i = 0; i < AMOUNT_CELLS; i++)
        {
            cell = new Button(this);
            cell.setId(i);
            cell.setHeight(cellWidth);

            cell.setOnClickListener(this);
            registerForContextMenu(cell);
            cells.add(cell);
        }
    }

    void createGridView()
    {
        GridView gv = findViewById(R.id.mGridView);
        gv.setAdapter(new CustomAdapter(cells));
    }
}
```

CustomAdapter.java:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;


public class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter
{
    private ArrayList<Button> mButtons;

    CustomAdapter(ArrayList<Button> b)
    {
        mButtons = b;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount()
    {
        return mButtons.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position)
    {
        return mButtons.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position)
    {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        Button button;
        if (convertView == null)
        {
            button = mButtons.get(position);
        }
        else
        {
            button = (Button) convertView;
        }
        return button;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
final int N = 3; // количество кнопок в ряду
Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
Point size = new Point();
display.getSize(size);
int width = size.x; // получаем ширину дисплея 

Button button;
//findViewById(...)
ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = button.getLayoutParams();
params.heigth = width/N;
button.setLayoutParams(params); // назначаем высоту кнопки
```